# Nginx says 404 Not Found when trying to serve an image from persistent storage

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

Following is my nginx config -

```
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    root /volume-bde-01/images;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass         http://<server-ip>:3000;
    }

    location /images {

    }
}
```

When I call `http://example.com/api`, it works fine and returns me the response from my server running at port `3000`. I need to upload images as a part of an api and need to directly display them later using the image src url (I was thinking). But some how the configuration doesn't work and gives mein `404 - Not Found`.

`/volume-bde-01/images;` is a persistent storage block attached to the server.

I tried `http://example.com/images/test.jpg`

NOTE - I believe its not mandatory to put the images in the same directory as running server's root as most of the examples are around that? We can place them anywhere, Isn't it?

P.S. -

It works for me with -

```
location /images/ {
          alias /volume-blr1-01/images/;
      }
```

But I wonder what difference is between `root` and `alias` ?

Answer (score 1):

The `alias` directive tells Nginx to replace what is defined in the `location` block with the path specified by the alias directive.

```
location ^~ /images {
   alias /var/www/static;
   try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

- `http://example.com/images/logo.png` into the file path `/var/www/static/logo.png`
- `http://example.com/images/third-party/facebook-logo.png` into the file path `/var/www/static/third-party/facebook-logo.png`

The `root` directive tells Nginx to take the request url and append it behind the specified directory.

```
location ^~ /images {
   root /var/www/static;
   try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

- `http://example.com/images/logo.png` into the file path `/var/www/static/images/logo.png`.
- `http://example.com/contact.html` into the file path `/var/www/example.com/contact.html`

Credits: https://www.techcoil.com/blog/understanding-the-difference-between-the-root-and-alias-directives-in-nginx/